# Can't Compile PHP 5.6.12 on Windows 10

Tags: php, windows-10

I setup a PHP build env as windows.php.net suggests, with php-sdk & the build tools. So I know it's not the enviroment. However, when I attempt to run my script to compile PHP:

```
call buildconf.bat
call configure.bat !PHP_ARGS! || exit /b
call nmake || exit /b
```

(rest can be found at [github](https://github.com/jaredallard/phc-win/blob/master/fetch_src.cmd))

This happens

```
Rebuilding configure.js
Now run 'configure --help'
Saving configure options to config.nice.bat
Checking for cl.exe ...  <in default path>
  Detected compiler undefined
C:\Users\rylor\Desktop\phc-win\src\depends\php-src\configure.js(2100, 9) Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'length' is null or not an object


Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23026.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified
Stop.
```

I read somewhere that this had something to do with the version of wscript last time this happened. However I found the version to be the one required, and since then have reinstalled a fresh build of Windows 10. What I find interesting is that it works fine on my desktop running a from Insider Preview build 10240, but not on a release 10240? It didn't work on the IP on this current machine last time.

It's not just 5.6.12, 5.6.6 won't build either.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Yes, I have called `vcvarsall.[bat/cmd]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As stated in the PHP wiki](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/compiler), PHP 5.6 cannot be built with Visual Studio 2015.

The solution is to install Visual Studio 2012/2013, or to upgrade to PHP 7.

Comment: Interesting! I got it to on my other machine, but perhaps it was just a lucky stride... Who knows... Anyways, thanks!